# Angular js to angular 5 migration

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, angular5

I am trying to migrate my angularjs(1.6) to angular 5. As of now I am focusing over migration of one page and want to go for both frameworks angular js and angular 5 running in same application.

I have gone through various links and found some approaches like going for incremental migration i.e. from angular js to angular 2 then angular 4 later angular 5 ; Modifying the scope syntaxes etc

My query is that should I modify the above scope related syntaxes in my current angular js application or I should create a new angular 2 /5 project and then move my js application code to newly created angular 2/5 app.My application is huge one. Also, I want to use ngUpgrade. Not sure where to use. Pls verify the approach and help in this migration

Comment: This [link](https://vsavkin.com/migrating-angular-1-applications-to-angular-2-in-5-simple-steps-40621800a25b) might help you. But I think you should create a completely new project to be able to edit and upgrade later, that's a good solution

Answer (score 1):

'create a new angular 2 /5 project and then move your js application code to newly created angular 2/5 app' is better in my opinion

there are some huge architecture differences between Angularjs and angular2+.

angular.js is a classic MV* architecture framework, you may write code in controllers, services, splitting these files into different folders like a MVC structure.

while angular2+ is a component based framework.you can write app in component based pattern.just like react or vue .although you still can write it as a MVC structure.but remember why you want to refactor your project.

Comment: But my application is a huge one.It will take time to rewrite the entire code.Cant I go live using angular-hybrid approach?

Comment: we also had a huge Angularjs project and we refractored it to a react version.what we tried to do was when we got new requirements ,we developed on the new one and moved the old project's  funcs to the new project gradually.

Comment: did u rewrite the entire code again i.e. old project's functions to the new application? manually using angular 2/react syntaxes?

Comment: yeah, we did, it's not that difficult.all you need is some time actually . so why you want to refactor your project? think Angularjs is slow or just wanna use new framework.

Comment: yes, we want to use new features of angular 5 and angular js is bit slow.Any idea over the https://medium.com/contentsquare-engineering-blog/angularjs-to-angular5-upgrading-a-large-application-7e6fbf70bafa

Comment: same as this org article: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade. personally not recommend.the code will  not be clean and maybe  you can't handle all the errors. besides, it's all up to you.it's better to start a entire new project in my opinion